# Issue related to getting data from persistance class in XPO

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xpo

I have added persistance classes in my web application using XPO from DevExpress.

Now I want to get data dynamically using XPQuery.
Dynamically means: 
I have got all the class names for particular assembly:

```
 Type[] typelist = typeof(Sample.Students).Assembly.GetTypes();
```

Now using `typelist[2]`, I want to get data from table containing typelist[2].

How can I do it? Tables are listed in `typelist` and based on that I have to create XPQuery<> object and then want to get data using LINQ Query:
How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```C#
// change typelist index as needed 
Type xpQueryGenericType = typeof (XPQuery<>).MakeGenericType(typelist[0]);
var xpQueryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(xpQueryGenericType, new object[]{xpoSession});
```